# IE generate corrupt image by file_put_contents of base64 image

Tags: php, internet-explorer, image-processing, corrupt

```
$imgPath = """BASE64 ENCODED STRING HERE""";

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imgPath);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = "test.png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

$html = '<img src="'.$file.'" />';
exit;
```

Here test.png created in ff/chrome fine... **but IE sucks and generate corrupt image.**

Comment: Why are you setting the content type to image/png and not outputting anything? If you want to display the image you could either `echo $data` or change the content type to text/html and `echo $html`.

Comment: I am storing that file and rander into pdf.
everywhere working fine except IE(IE generates image but corrupt image that can not open)

Comment: If it works everywhere else, the problem is not in this PHP code. How are you generating the image in the browser?

Comment: code is as above...
as this will generate test.png image.

Comment: PLEASE don't follow this question as..
I had error in javascript function 

var img = $('#chart2').jqplotToImage(50, 0);

The above function jqplotToImage not support IE 7,8 version.